# How to attach redirecting script with two id's?

Tags: javascript

this is redirecting script it works with only 1 id if i want to add this script with two id's so what i have to change in the script

```
 function loadBody() {
     var elem = document.getElementById("mycontent");
    if(elem.innerHTML != "Stackoverflow" || elem.getAttribute("href") != "http://www.stackoverflow.com")
    window.location="http://www.stackoverflow.com"; 
    } 
window.onload=loadBody ;

 <a href='http://www.Stackoverflow.com' id='mycontent'>Stackoverflow</a>
```

if i want to attach this script with this line also so what i have to change in this script?

```
<a href='http://www.newid.com' id='newid'>Newid</a>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want this script to run with every anchor on the page, only two specified anchors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

havent tested but it should work

js

```
function loadBody(the_id, the_url)
{
    var elem = document.getElementById(the_id);
    if(elem.innerHTML.toLowerCase() != the_url.toLowerCase() || elem.getAttribute("href").toLowerCase() != "http://www."+the_url.toLowerCase()+".com")
    window.location="http://www."+the_url.toLowerCase()+".com"; 
} 

function loadBody_loader()
{
    loadBody("mycontent","mywebsite1111111");
    loadBody("mycontent2","mywebsite2222222");
}

window.onload=loadBody_loader();
```

html

```
<a href='http://www.mywebsite1111111.com' id='mycontent'>mywebsite1111111</a>

<a href='http://www.mywebsite2222222.com' id='mycontent2'>mywebsite2222222</a>
```

update: yes, its working here (alerts instead of redirects)

**UPDATED: http://jsfiddle.net/5snhg/2/**

as you can understand you can add more loadBody("name_of_id") inside the loadBody_loader

Comment: but you only gived me the code of 1st id and what is script of id='mycontent2' ?

Comment: @user2397942 im sorry i cant understand what you are asking. please be more clear so i can help you

Comment: i have two html here : <a href='http://www.templateify.com' id='Notify'>Templateif</a> &amp; <a href='http://www.collegetalks.net' id='Notes'>CollegeTalks</a> 

i want to attach this script with these two id's

Comment: @user2397942 then just change inside the loadBody_loader  the "mycontent" to "Notify" and "mycontent2" to "Notes"

Comment: but as you can see   var elem = document.getElementById(the_id);
you have given of 1st id but i want for two id's 1st: Templateify and 2nd: collegetalks.

Comment: @user2397942 is this ok now?